# jQuery - Fill input with img tag then append it

Tags: jquery, image, input, escaping

The input does not show the input tag correctly, I tried many variations to escape the quotes but I get the same result! The img tag in the newly prepended input gets  cut off at the quote. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="student-info">
  <img src="students/24535.jpg" />
</div>

var imgSrc = $('#student-info').find('img').attr('src'); 
var imgCode = '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" />';
$('#student-info').prepend('<span class="img-code"><input type="text" value="'+imgCode+'"></span>');
```

The output shows `<img src=` in the input tag and then `">` after the input tag. How can I get the final output to look like this (so I can copy it from the input):

```
<span class="img-code"><input type="text" value="<img src="students/24535.jpg" />"></span>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbp2W/)

Comment: That is because you can't put tags inside an `<input type="text"/>` tag's value attribute.

Comment: why you dont use css for the image in your input?

Comment: Better yet, what exactly are you hoping to gain by sticking an image inside a text-input field?

Comment: it should work as an image embed code, not to have the actual image there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this :

```
value="'+imgCode+'"
```

**To this :**

```
value=\''+imgCode+'\'
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbp2W/2/).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Vinc!

Comment: Do you understand why Vinc's solution worked? It's because your imgCode already has text that includes double-quotes inside it (for the img src attribute), which, in your version, was early-terminating the attribute value and causing the display to go funky. Just thought I'd clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a slightly different approach:

```
var imgSrc = $('#student-info').find('img').attr('src'); 
var imgCode = '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" />';

$('#student-info').prepend('<span class="img-code"><input type="text"></span>');
$('input').val(imgCode);
```

Comment: Actually, I somewhat favor this approach. It allows you to not mess with as much escaping, which translates (in my head) as fewer opportunities to accidentally mess up and end up with mismatched quotes.